# How to rename the Windows Guest Account using C# code?

Tags: c#, windows

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName +     ",Computer");
DirectoryEntry admGroup = localMachine.Children.Find("Users");
object members = admGroup.Invoke("members", null);
foreach (object groupMember in (IEnumerable)members)
DirectoryEntry member = new DirectoryEntry(groupMember);
Console.WriteLine(member.Name);                
Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In the output,I am getting list of the local accounts under "Users".But the built in Guest account is not getting displayed.

Comment: can you show what you have done?

Comment: I am trying to write C# code for it

Comment: Did you google it around?
In Stackoverflow, we appreciate people who play around first and try things on there end and them come to stackoverflow.
You question is closed due to this reason only.
Please take care this for next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the username of a user account with the NetUserSetInfo function.

Comment: NetUserGetInfo is a Win32 unmanaged function.How to invoke it in managed .Net code?